# Is the proposal creator guaranteed moderator status?

Tags: support, area-51, moderators, pro-tem-moderators

When an Area 51 site goes into public beta is the person who created the proposal one of the pro tem moderators or not?

They are talking on Area 51 about combining all the sports proposals into http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports, including one I proposed. Would I still be one of the pro tem moderators on the merged site?

Is the proposal creator afforded any elevated status or perk?

Comment: depend on the participation .. if you are contributing good enough than possibilities are higher

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer is no, not automatically.  I thought i recall a member of the community team stat in a comment that to be named a *pro tem* moderator, you have to earn it (during the beta phase).  Trying to find a reference now

Comment: No. During beta SE appoints some moderators, typically from those that contributed during the beginning of the beta. Being the "founder" is probably considered as some form as contribution, but certainly not as the only one. Permanent moderators will be elected once the site comes out of beta (rarely faster than a year)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The author of the proposal does not automatically become a moderator nor receive any special privileges.

Please read [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) which discusses how early supporters of a site can become moderators. Specifically, the section titled *How Moderators are Appointed Pro Tem*.

In short, we look at who is participating in the site and growing the site once the site actually gets created.  Anyone can fill out a few fields in a form.

After a site graduates, it will hold its normal moderator elections where people nominate themselves and the community votes.

Comment: I have read the post but what if I was the one who created the proposal?

Comment: As I said, we look at who is participating in the site and its meta, not who filled out a web form.

Comment: @Benny, In short: Being the person creating the proposal does not give you any special privileges whatsoever. Quite a few sites have been proposed by users that never became moderators, or even finished commitment on the sites.

Answer (score 10):

No, you don't.

Stack Exchange community managers will act as diamond moderators at first, then will invite members they feel might fit the job description as Pro Tem moderators. Criteria include activity on the new site itself, as well as experience with other Stack Exchange sites.

Pro Tem moderators then act as liaison between the Stack Exchange team and the new site community until the first proper moderator elections are held.

Quoting from the [blog post that introduced the Pro Tem moderator concept](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/):

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

As initiator of the site at Area 51 it *may* be that you have exhibited these traits, but it is not a given that you are offered a Pro Tem diamond position *just* because you started the ball rolling.